# jquerymobile selectmenu not populating

Tags: php, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to populate a selected menu when the page is created but there are no options that show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax('patientlist.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].patient_id + '">' + data[i].patient_firstname + data[i].patient_lastname + '</option>';}
    $('#patientselect').append(html);
});
```

});

my patientlist.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `patient_id`, `patient_firstname`, `patient_lastname` FROM `patients` WHERE `company_id` = " . $user_data['company_id'] . " ORDER BY `patient_firstname`");
```

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

```
$data[] = $row;

echo json_encode( $data );
```

}
My result from the php page

[{"patient_id":"9","patient_firstname":"Adam","patient_lastname":"Steve"}] etc...

Really appreciate any help, been stuck on this for a week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, posting again.

First of all, you should put the `echo json_encode( $data );` out of your while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Second, your `$ajax` syntax isn't correct, change this to `$.post` and tell the `$.post` request you are expecting a `'json'` response from `patientlist.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post('patientlist.php', {}, function(data){
    /* code */
  }, 'json'); // <= set data type json here
});
```

When retrieving a valid `json` string, you can iterate over `data` by using the `$.each` method

```
$.each(data, function(index, patient) {
  console.log(patient.patient_id); // or use patient['patient_id']
});
```

At least you will now receive a valid request.

Noticing your HTML, do not use `.append` if it is not a DOM element, you are just building  html elements as a string, so use instead

```
$('#patientselect').html(html);
```

Comment: Im using dreamweaver cs5 if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Adam updated the post, sorry for that, everything was just scrambled after my second edit.

Comment: how do I show you my revised code? Sorry Im completely new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: THANK YOU! Your code worked perfectly, I just needed to add     complete: function () {
      $('#patientselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
To rebuild to select menu.